# Combinatorics - How many orders are possible, from a chef's and waiter's perspective?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A family of $7$ are out to lunch and each of them orders one dish from a menu of $12$ dishes.

- (a) From the waiter’s perspective, how many orders are possible?
- (b) From the chef’s perspective, how many orders are possible?
- (c) What is the effect of changing the perspective in the above?

I tried $_{12}C_7$ for both (a) & (b), but I don't understand what's the difference between each perspective. Aren't they the same?

Comment: The waiter will care who ordered which dish. The chef will not.

Comment: @farruhota Slight problem with that (I fell into the same hole and deleted my answer): what if two people order the same meal? Those formulas don't account for such repetition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the chef, it’s the number of solutions to $n_1+n_2+ \dots + n_{12} = 7$ ($n_i$ is the number of diners ordering menu item number $i$), or $18\choose7$. For the waiter, it’s $12^7$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I get it now :)

Comment: It’s called “stars and bars.” To count the ways, count the number of ways to write* * | * | | | * * | | |... with *s for the meals, first group is item 1 orders, etc., with 11 separators meaning “switch to next menu item.”

Answer (score 1):

The chef doesn't care who orders what - his job is just to cook the meals. However, on the other hand, the waiter needs to give the meal to the right person - in that sense, he *does* care who ordered what.

In that light, you would find the number of **permutations** from the waiter's perspective  and the number of **combinations** from the chef's.

Note, however, that you must find these numbers *with repetition accounted for*. For example, you posit the answer $_{12}C_7$; this is not correct from either perspective, since it assumes choice without repetition. Each of the $7$ people can choose one of $12$ meals, but they could all (hypothetically) order the same meal, you see?

So we note: for $k$ objects taken **with replacement/repetition** from a group of $n$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\text{# of permutations with reptition} &= n^k\\
\text{# of combinations with reptition} &= _{n+k-1}C_k = \binom{n+k-1}{k} = \frac{(n+k-1)!}{k! (n-1)!}\\
\end{align}$$

Hopefully this should be sufficient to guide you to the right answer, neglecting me overlooking something (such as repetition when I first posted this).

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks :)